# How to focus on html select on page load or button click in react js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm creating a react js application, and using HTML select dropdown. I want to focus on select when page load. below shows which code I'm using in select.

```
<select id="sel_bookID" autofocus> 
  <option value="binary"> 
    Binary Search 
  </option> 
  <option value="linear"> 
    Linear Search 
  </option> 
  <option value="interpolation"> 
    Interpolation Search 
  </option> 
</select>
```

I'm also using below mention some StackOverflow solution but did not work.

```
//jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sel_bookID').focus();
});
```

or

```
//javascript
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    document.getElementById('sel_bookID').focus();
}, false);
```

Comment: you need to use `focus` in `componentDidMount`, you have tried is javascript and jquery way.

Comment: sorry , my mistake .i'm not add id property, but also add id it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
<select autofocus>
```

should have an id attribute, like so:

```
<select autofocus id="selectElem">
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('selectElem').focus();
};
```

Comment: not working sir, sorry my mistake before post not properly check. but id also added not working .

Comment: window.onload also using but not working .this is existing solutions available on stackoverflow.

Comment: That should work, well can you add complete code, including react.js implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an id attribute to your select tag like this:

```
<select autofocus id="sel_bookID"> 
  <option value="binary"> 
    Binary Search 
  </option> 
  <option value="linear"> 
    Linear Search 
  </option> 
  <option value="interpolation"> 
    Interpolation Search 
  </option> 
</select>
```

otherwise, your js script cannot find an element with id sel_bookID and returns undefined

Comment: not working in react js. this one i had tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is react way using refs:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myRef.current.focus();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <select ref={this.myRef}>
          <option value="react">React</option>
          <option value="vue">Vue</option>
          <option value="angular">Angular</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

[CodeSandBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-resonance-9x5j5)

If you prefer `autofocus` option you have to use `autoFocus` to make it work

Comment: errors comes in console  "l.a.createRef is not a function".

Comment: I have no idea what `l.a.createRef` means, as you can see there are no errors in example. As I said the easiest way for you will be using `autoFocus` prop.

Comment: Code Sandbox example also not working.

Comment: i don't no why autofocus not working in react js when html select using.bcoz no.of solution availbale in stackoverflow i had already tried,after that i put in stackoverflow

Comment: Did you click refresh in codesandbox browser(iframe)?

Comment: yes refresh, but not working.this issue taken my entire day.